# Reversing an unbounded string without checking for null character

Tags: c, string

Recently in an interview, I was asked to write a code to reverse an unbounded string without checking for the null character. I don't know the length of the string and cannot use any library function in any form..

---

I wrote the following code ( which I know is incorrect due to many reasons, one being I am not terminating the string with '\0', instead I am terminating it with CTRL+Z or CTRL+D)

---

```
while(scanf("%c",arr[i++])!=-1);
```

---

```
for(i--;i>=0;i--)
     puts(arr[i]);
```

---

What can be the possible algorithm !!

Comment: Do you mean that you should print it in reverse? Not store it in reverse in the original array?

Comment: Even printing in reverse should do, I guess !!

Comment: I am not sure I am following, but if you get the string from the input, and you can read it char by char - you can count its length and treat it as any array... of course if it is unbounded - dynamic allocation will be needed.

Comment: did he specified any length????

Comment: No... the string is unbounded.. I also suggested a push-pop mechanism on stack.. But he then asked, till when will you push and when will you start to pop !!

Comment: Coding questions in an interview are a bad way to verify if someone can code, because you exclude a rather big group of people that cannot think straight under heavy stress (= job interview). You should just have said *I google the solution and if nothing pops up I go to the bathroom and think about it while I XXX* which comes much closer to the real work situation later on, so you show that you know how to google (a skill a lot of co-workers here have **not**).

Comment: If the string is __unbounded__ please define "reverse".
Can I ask you to count DOWN from the infinite to 0 ? I don't think so. If you have no boundary you cannot have a "reverse" order.

Comment: May be interviewer fooling you!!!! just wanted to hear not possible..

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like:

```
void
reverse_print(const char* string) {
    if (*string == 0) {
       return;
    }
    reverse_print(string + 1);
    putchar(*string);
}
```

Or, reading the string from input:

```
void
reverse_print() {
    char c;
    if (1 != scanf("%c", &c)) {
        return;
    }
    reverse_print();
    putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: *without checking for the null character*

Comment: I'm interpreting that as that you're not allowed to first find the length of the string.

Comment: Could be wrong - but personally - I see no justification for this permissive interpertation.

Comment: If you're not allowed to inspect the content of the string, I can't see how you could create an algorithm that terminates.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char* string1 = "This is me the right guy!! understood !!!";
  char* string = string1;
  char *nonstring = "\x01\x05\x0a\x15";
  int len = 0;

  while ((*string ^ nonstring[0]) && (*string ^ nonstring[1])
      && (*string ^ nonstring[2]) && (*string ^ nonstring[3])
      && (*string ^ nonstring[4]))
  {
    len++;
    string++;
  }
  //printf("%d\n", len); 
  while(len)
  {
    printf("%c", string1[--len]);
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are reading the string from input, and trying to print it.

You can just count the number of characters, and treat it like it was a normal array, something along the lines of:

```
int main() { 
int i = 0;
char arr[256];
while(scanf("%c",arr + (i++))!=-1);
for(i = i-1; i+1; i--) putchar(arr[i]);

return 0;
}
```

If the array is completely unbounded, you will have to make sure you are not out of space, and if you are - reallocate it.

You can also add a NULL terminator manually when you are done. Since, it is not *checking* for it, you should be fine with the requirements.

Comment: Well, then again this is what I did. But here you are not terminating a string with a null character. So effectively, you just have a character array and not a string !!

Comment: @CSSS: Your comment suggests it is fine: `Even printing in reverse should do, I guess !! ` You can always add the NULL character manually (and you just *add* it, not *checking* for it, so it is also fine)